# How do change one position in an array when the index is unknown?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of Strings, and when I initialized the array, i made all the entries "".

later, I need to find the first position in the array where the entry is " and change it to my variable tag. The problem is, whenever I run my code, it changes all the entries to tag.

```
String[] list = new String[100];

for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    list[i] = "";
}
//Other method
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

    if(list[i].equals("")){
        list[i] = tag;
    }
}
```

This is part of a homework assignment, so I can't use any predefined java API structures or import most things.

Comment: You mean all *blank* entries? Well, of course, you're not exiting the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `break` from the loop after the first change to avoid changing all the entries to `tag`:

```
//Other method
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

    if(list[i].equals("")){
        list[i] = tag;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I place the break? In the if loop or the for loop?

Comment: (you place it right after the `list[i] = tag;` line in the `if` statement of the `for` loop). @newarsenic